# Matlab GUI text input, return array

Tags: arrays, matlab, user-interface, input

I made this GUI:

[image]

Al the inputs are single numbers. To convert these numbers to usefull data isn't a problem. For example for the input 'Temperature at MSL' :

```
T0=str2double(get(handles.T0_input,'string'))+273.15; %K sealevel
```

However, the Wind Speed input and Wind Direction input isn't a single number, but has to be a array. The final result has to be something as:

```
Vwind=[10 10 12 14 16 15 18 20];
```

But how can I convert this kind of input to the required array?

Comment: See: [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)

Comment: `str2num` does the trick...

Comment: `str2num` replaces spaces with semicolons and wraps the string in brackets, passing the result to an `eval` call. `str2double` utilizes a more robust `sscanf` implementation, which I would recommend for an edit box so users don't break (or abuse) `str2num`'s `eval` call.